# .Net Core Multi-Language Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to do a *simple* multi-language web app with routes.

What I want to do is in the url:
**en/products** and
**it/prodotti**
with the same action.

I have created two differend routes with same action/controller:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "english",
    template: "en/products",
    defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "products" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "italiano",
    template: "it/prodotti",
    defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "products" }
);
```

When I want to call one of theese routes I use:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("english", new { Action = "home", Controller = "products"})">Products</a>
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("italiano", new { Action = "home", Controller = "products"})">Prodotti</a>
```

And I get url **en/products** or
**it/prodotti**

The problem is, when I want to make a form post, I cannot control which url is going to return.

```
<form asp-action="products" method="post">
```

This **only** returns the first value of my routes.

**The question is**, how can I control my routes when I sending a form like I'm doing with Url.RouteUrl link?

I tried this but this also not works:

```
[Route("it/prodotti")]
[Route("en/products")]
public ViewResutl products() {
    ...
    return View(new viewmodel...);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great news, finally i have found the answer.

```
    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm("routenamehere"))
    {
    <form>
    ...
    ...
    </form>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's 5 years too late, but I believe now it can be achieved with the Dynamic Routes

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<TranslationTransformer>("{language}/{controller}/{action}");
    });
```

And then your transformer would do the replacements of controller and action names:

```
public TranslationTransformer(TranslationDatabase translationDatabase)
{
    _translationDatabase = translationDatabase;
}

public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    if (!values.ContainsKey("language") || !values.ContainsKey("controller") || !values.ContainsKey("action")) {
        return values;
    }

    var language = (string)values["language"];
    var controller = await _translationDatabase.Resolve(language, (string)values["controller"]);
    if (controller == null) {
        return values;
    }
    values["controller"] = controller;

    var action = await _translationDatabase.Resolve(language, (string)values["action"]);
    if (action == null) {
        return values;
    }
    values["action"] = action;

    return values;
}
```

translation database can be a static dictionary that simply maps english names to any other language. That way you're not limited only to english and italian and can even change the behaviour in runtime.

The code above comes from the solution proposed in this post:
https://medium.com/@fedonman/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-5-ac81a6bb8a95

Answer (score 0):

its a lot deeper than surface changes.  Found a reference to the topic by Damien Bod,

1. https://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/
2. https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5Localization/tree/master/src/AspNetCoreLocalization

source and his write up on the topic.

in the explanation while it does involve an ActionFilter associated to the webapi he demonstrated.  I think its a starting point for you situation.